# Android - getting values

Tags: java, android

```
test=0;
Phone phone=new Phone();
phone.phone="01093575777";
WebService.getInstance().getApi().checkNumber(phone).enqueue(new Callback<MainResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MainResponse> call, Response<MainResponse> response) {
        if (response.body().status==1){
            test++;
            //----------------->first place
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MainResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});

//----------------->second place
```

when I print the value from first place it is equal to 1 and that is what i want

but when printing it from second place it's equal to 0

why ?? and how to solve this

Comment: Where is the error message? Does `Log.d("DEBUG:["+ contactsString[0]; +"]");` show you a valid number?

Comment: yes it does . the problem is when I assign the mobile number value directly to the web service it works well but when I assign it from string array with index it doesn't

Comment: May be the array string have spaces with the values. Try trimming the value from the string array before sending.

Comment: it's trimmed and correct .. found out something the problem isn't with assigning .. inside the onResponse when I print the respone it's right that means it's working the problem is now that although it's correct it don't change the count or making any mathematical action inside the onResponse

Comment: Are you performing the above piece of code in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the value of `test`. You schedule a call to check the number asynchronously. Some time in the future the result will come back and `onResponse` will be executed. This happens after you reach "second place". Therefore `test` is still 0 when you print it there.

Comment: you are correct I will accept this but one last question I am making a for loop to check for all numbers in a list with all numbers in the online database how to avoid getting wrong values ?

Comment: Use as many result variables as you have numbers to check, for example an array of booleans and write your `onResponse` in such a way that it updates the correct variable.